# Node redirect without changing url

Tags: node.js, angular, redirect, host

Is possible to redirect to another host but maintaining the same url without doing manually the request?
For example I call

```
GET http://host1.com/home
```

this loads content from

```
http://host2.com/home
```

but mainaining the first url in browser. I don't want to replicate the request manually, I home to use a framework that to it for me.

I'm using node to handle the redirect operations, here is an example

```
main1.host.com                                                           localhost:3000
main2.host.com  -- points to --> mypc.com -- that loads content from --> localhost:3001
main3.host.com                                                           localhost:3002
```

Comment: As far as I know, the only way is to use framing, but browsers reaaaally don't like it, as it presents obvious potential security issues.

Comment: So how the domain dns services do that??

Comment: It isn't the DNS. You simply set up an `<iframe src="http://host2.com/home">` at `http://host1.com/home". I really cannot recommend you do this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: TBH I'm not even sure if it still works. Browsers tend to throw a fit.

Comment: I have a server with some web applications, multiple address points to my server endpoint and inside it I have to route my request between th applications

Comment: for example.. main.myhost.com, database.myhost.com -> homepc.com -> localhost:3000, localhost:3001

Comment: I assume, because of the question tags, that you're using Angular. Is there any reason you can't just use the HttpClient?

Comment: My web app are in angular, but I want to use a node server to do the routing operations

Comment: Which routing operations? I'm afraid your question isn't clear. I still don't know exactly what you're trying to do. Please edit the question with at least one example of precisely what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: can you understand better now?

Comment: Well, you can use frame forwarding, which as I said I don't recommend. You could also possibly change the CNAME entry and simply have `main1.host.com`, `main2.host.com` etc simply point to whatever server `mypc.com` points to.

Comment: I've tryied node-iframe-replacement node library, do you know it? But I've an issue loading my page

Comment: I don't know the library. Either manually implement an `<iframe>` or simply use the CNAME DNS entry to point your domains at the server you need.

Comment: Can you explain how to set up CNAME DNS?

Comment: I've never tried for the way you're doing things, only when setting up a normal domain. Check with your domain service and do the necessary research.

Comment: In this way I cannot reply path

Comment: What do you mean?